# hyperledger fabric upgrading to 1.2 fails : "Local Fabric binary version of 1.1.0-alpha does not match this newer version of BYFN and is unsupported"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to upgrade to 1.2. I follow the documentation "Upgrade your components network" using byfn. (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/upgrading_your_network_tutorial.html#launch-a-v1-1-network)

When I run : `./byfn.sh up -t 3000 -i 1.1.0`

I got this error :

```
    LOCAL_VERSION=1.1.0-alpha
    DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.1.0
    =================== WARNING ===================
      Local fabric binaries and docker images are  
      out of  sync. This may cause problems.       
    ===============================================
    ERROR! Local Fabric binary version of 1.1.0-alpha does not match this newer version of BYFN and is unsupported. Either move to a later version of Fabric or checkout an earlier version of fabric-samples.
```

The documentation says that I have to clean up images and run the example again. So I did, I removed all images with `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)` and I run the example again.
Images have been downloaded again and I still got this error about the 1.1.0-alpha version.

Obvisously, I am missing something...
Does someone have any clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have the alpha version of the binaries used by the sample.
I'd suggest deleting the "fabric-samples/bin" directory and then downloading  v1.1.0 again:

```
cd fabric-samples
rm -Rf bin
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed ! You are my hero <3

Comment: Yes... That's because upgrade procedure will not replace fabric binaries. This should be documented.